# IRC Bot Echo Function Python

Tags: python, sockets, bots, irc

I've searched all over the net, but cannot find anything. I need to make an "echo" function in which the person types .echo (word that is going to be "echoed) and the bot reads it and sends the word back twice.

I assume I have to use some kind of split string?

https://github.com/KingInTheNorth/TeenBot/blob/master/TeenBot.py

```
def echo():
    ircsock.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + "")

if ircmsg.find(":.echo") != -1:
    ircmsg.find.split(":.echo")
```

I've had variations of this, but cannot think of anything. Sadly there is no documentations. BTW: I am a beginner who is a teenager hence the name TeenBot

Thanks.

Comment: One issue I see with this is that you're taking each `recv` call as a whole message: `ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048)` reads in 2048 bytes from the socket - but not all messages are 2048 bytes. You're probably going to want to be appending them to your own buffer and processing them when you hit a newline, and then you can know that you've read an entire line (and not a part of a line, like "ello there\r\nPING :ir", then "c.freenode.net"). If you have the whole line instead, you can perform more accurate matches on the text than checking if it contains ":.echo", which could come up errantly.

Comment: Additionally, the `PONG` reply should contain the information that the `PING` sent you - if you receive `PING :irc.freenode.net`, you should reply with `PONG :irc.freenode.net`, not `PONG :pingis`